# Python filter numbers within optional bounds (use less if-else)

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to select elements from list of numbers within lower and upper bounds, each of which is optional. I can write it as a series of if and else for all possible cases. Can we reduce these branching and write in a concise way?

```
def select_within_bounds(li, lower=None, upper=None):
    if lower is None:
        if upper is None:
            return li
        else:
            return [v for v in li if v <= upper]
    else:
        if upper is None:
            return [v for v in li if v >= lower]
        else:
            return [v for v in li if lower <= v <= upper]

#example:
my_list = [1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 9]
print(select_within_bounds(my_list))
print(select_within_bounds(my_list, 3, 8))
print(select_within_bounds(my_list, lower=3))
print(select_within_bounds(my_list, upper=8))
print(select_within_bounds(my_list, lower=3,upper=8))

#results in 
[1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 9]
[4, 5, 3, 6]
[4, 5, 3, 6, 9]
[1, 4, 5, 3, 6]
[4, 5, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def select_within_bounds(li, lower=float('-inf'), upper=float('inf')):
    return [v for v in li if lower <= v <= upper]
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, using python's [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) built-in function. Like so:

```
def select_within_bounds(li, lower=None, upper=None):
    return filter(lambda x: (x if lower is None else lower) <= x <= (x if upper is None else upper), li)
```

Comment: this will fail is one of the boundaries is 0

Comment: @Copperfield thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You know the answer when the numeric bounds are always present. So, you can first derive the bounds and then apply the same logic. That is:

```
def select_within_bounds(li, lower=None, upper=None):
    lower = min(li) if lower is None else lower 
    upper = max(li) if upper is None else upper
    return [v for v in li if lower <= v <= upper]
```

**Updated:** based on @Copperfield's comment:
we can avoid calumniating min/max by using default boundaries as symbolic infinities (linear vs constant cost)

```
lower = float("-inf") if lower is None else lower 
upper = float("inf") if upper is None else upper
```

Comment: Hi, you don't need to take the trouble of calculating `min(li)` and `max(li)` if you change your list comprehension to `[v for v in li if (v if lower is None else lower) <= v <= (v if upper is None else upper)]` :)

Comment: I think this is more readable, and even in terms of performance not worse.

Comment: Instead of calculating the min or max, which are linear search in the list, is better to use `float("-inf")` and `float("inf")` as default boundaries

Comment: this will fail is the upper limit is 0

Comment: updated. The accepted answer putl all of these in succinct form.